# CGPath on CALayer

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ipod

I want to draw CGPath on CALayer, but when I render CGPath in CALayer it always draw in the main UIView. Tell me how can I draw CGPath on CALayer.

When I try to draw path on CALayer it gives me something like this:

**Image:**
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/h1k7e

Comment: check the link http://www.raywenderlich.com/2502/introduction-to-calayers-tutorial

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a CAShapeLayer and its 'path' property to draw a CGPath to a CALayer.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAShapeLayer/path

Answer (score 2):

check out this site. http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/tutorial-drawing-to-the-screen.132024/